# Flattening json such that one property is key and the other value

Tags: javascript, json

I have data in following format..

```
var array = [{"name":"abc","boss":"def","sub":[{"schema":"a","data":1},{"schema":"b","data":0},{"schema":"c","data":0}]},
.
.
.
]
```

I wish to transform it to the following structure:

```
[{"name":"abc","boss":"def","a":1,"b":0,"c":0},
    .
    .
    .
    ]
```

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417031/convert-json-data-to-another-format-using-javascript).. I tried..

```
grouped = [];
array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.name]||!this[a.boss]) {
        this[a.name] = { name: a.name, boss:a.boss };
        grouped.push(this[a.name]);
       }
    this[a.name][a.sub.schema] = (this[a.name][a.sub.schema] || 0) + a.sub.data;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

The above gives undefined:NaN as the third property in the result objects..

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `a.sub` is an array. You will have to iterate over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to `reduce` the `sub` object to properties of the item.

The following code maps the items in `array` to a new array, which contains the flattened items:

```
array = array.map(function(item) {
   item = item.sub.reduce(function(x,y) { return x[y.schema] = y.data, x; }, item);
   delete item.sub;
   return item;
});
```

Comment: Liked the use of __`Comma operator`__

Answer (score 2):

Try this simply.

```
var arr = [];
array.forEach(function(ele){
  var obj = {};obj.name=ele.name;
  obj.boss=ele.boss;
  ele.sub.forEach(function(e){
    obj[e.schema] = e.data
  });
  arr.push(obj)
});
```